# Como importar a library Vue2Vis?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Estava tentando criar uma TimeLine utilizando o Vis.js,utilizando o Vuejs 2 adapter for Visjs,(https://github.com/alexcode/vue2vis) e ocorreu o seguinte erro :[image: Cannot_read_the_property_'TimeLine' of undefined].

Deve ser algum erro de importação.Se alguém puder ajudar, segue o código:

```js
import vue2vis from 'vue2vis';
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('timeline', vue2vis.Timeline);
const ItemComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>{{item.content}}</p>',
    props: ['item'],
});
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            groups: [{
                id: 0,
                content: 'Group 1'
            }],
            items: [{
                id: 0,
                group: 0,
                start: new Date(),
                content: 'Item 1'
            }],
            options: {
                editable: true,
                template: (item) => {
                    return new ItemComponent({
                        store: this.$store,
                        parent: this,
                        propsData: {
                            item,
                        },
                    }).$mount().$el;
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

```html
<div id="visualization" ref="myDiv">
    <timeline ref="timeline" :items="items" :groups="groups" :options="options">
    </div>
</div>
```

Desde já Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Já tentou fechar a tag do componente <timeline> ? ou importar o vue antes do vue2vis ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu sou novato no uso do vue2vis, mas com a versao 0.0.15 eu nao precisei importar Vue ou vue2vis:

```
<script>
import { Timeline } from 'vue2vis';

export default {
    ...
}
</script>
```

Veja o exemplo completo [aqui](https://github.com/alexcode/vue2vis/blob/master/examples/src/App.vue).

Se tiver algum error com o `vue2vis.css`, use

```
@import '~vue2vis/dist/vue2vis.css'
```

no lugar de

```
@import 'vue2vis/dist/vue2vis.css'`
```